# RSpec factories with FactoryBot 'uninitialized constant FactoryBot'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, factory-bot

I am setting up request specs following [this tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-json-api-with-rails-5-part-one). 
If I run the tests with `bundle exec rspec` I get the following error:

```
An error occurred while loading ./spec/factories/entities_spec.rb.
Failure/Error:
  FactoryBot.define do
    factory :entity do
      name { FFaker::Lorem.word }
    end
  end

NameError:
  uninitialized constant FactoryBot
```

The tutorial only asks to add some configuration to the rails_helper.rb file. I can't figure where I need to add a `require 'factory_bot'`. If I add it to the top of the rails_helper.rb file, the error persists. And if I add it to the factories/entity_spec.rb file, I get this error:

```
An error occurred while loading ./spec/requests/entities_spec.rb.
Failure/Error:
  factory :entity do
    name { FFaker::Lorem.word }
  end

FactoryBot::DuplicateDefinitionError:
  Factory already registered: entity
```

Comment: Hm, why is there a factory definition in your _spec file_?

Comment: It's not in there. Because then the DuplicateDefinitionError gets thrown.

Comment: I was using `FactoryBot` in my `ActionMailer::Preview` class, which was in the `development` environment and my `factory_bot_rails` gem was only in the `test` group. So I moved it to our group for `test` _and_ `development`.

Answer (score 1):

Simply renaming my `factories/*.rb` files from e.g. `factories/user_spec.rb` to `factories/user.rb` solved the problem.